# Implementation for user defined Exception

Tags: java, exception, user-defined

I have been searching online and researching in some books, but the examples given are limited and I still have some doubts in user-defined exception.

Using the following codes as an example:

```
//Conventional way of writing user-defined exception
class IdException extends Exception  

{
    public IdException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }   
}

class Product
{
    String id = new String();
    public Product(String _id) throws IdException
    {
        id = _id;

        //Check format of id
        if (id.length() < 5)
            throw(new IdException(_id));
    }
}
```

It seems that the conventional way of writing a user-defined exception is almost always the same. In the constructor of the user-defined exception, we always call `super(msg)`. This triggers a question in me: If most exceptions are implemented this way, what difference are there between all these exceptions?

For example, I can have multiple user-defined exceptions, but all seems to do the same thing without any differences. (There is no implementation in these exceptions, what makes them work?)

**Example:**

```
class IdException extends Exception
{
    public IdException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }   
}

class NameException extends Exception
{
    public NameException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }   
}

class ItemException extends Exception
{
    public ItemException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }   
}
```

**QUE:** So shouldn't we (for example) implement the checking of `id` inside the exception class? If not all exception classes just seem to do the same thing (or not doing anything).

**Example of implementing the check in an Exception:**

```
class IdException extends Exception     {
    public IdException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        //Can we either place the if-statements here to check format of id ?
    }
    //Or here ? 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should not implement your business logic inside Exception. Exception tells information about exceptional behaviour, And in Custom Exception you can customise that information.

Find the [best practice](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue162.html) to write Custom Exception.

Comment: That is the point I do not understand. If we don't implement the logic within the exceptions. In my example, `IdException`, `NameException`, & `ItemException` all seems to does the same thing. So why do we still implement so many exception which does the same stuff? Thanks.

Comment: @user3437460 The type of the exceptions can be reused in code to produce different branches for different types of exceptions in `try { ... } catch (...) { ... }` blocks (see @sp00ms answer) and you can create a formatted Message from key parameters to make `throw` code more readable and still produce a nice and readable message text (see my answer).

Comment: Custom Exceptions are reasons for custom causes. In each custom Exception you can customise your information very specifically.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder All along I thought exception should have the capabilities to check varaious types of error by themselves. For now, it seems that we have to manually `try`, `catch` these errors and manually categorize them to the right exception? Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes thats right. That is basic of `try-catch(Exception)-finally(optional)`.

Answer (score 0):

We have so many Exceptions already defined in java. All do the same thing : `to notify user about the problem in code`.

Now suppose we have only one Exception, then How we can what error occurs when the exception is thrown. After all, name matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To take your example Exceptions, I would create a more elaborate message by *formatting* the data provided:

```
public IdException(String id, String detail) {
    super(String.format("The id \"%s\" is invalid: %s", id, detail));
}

throw new IdException(_id, "Id too short.");
```

This way there is no real logic in the `IdException` class other than providing the given value (`id`) and a detail message together in the `e.getMessage()` String so debugging and logging is easy to read and the code itself is also straightforward:

> There is something wrong with the Id `_id`, namely it is too short. Thus we throw it back at the caller.

Also, when you throw different types of Exceptions in a code, it allows caller code to handle each Exception type differently:

```
try {
    getItem(id, name);
} catch (IdException ex) {
    fail(ex.getMessage()); // "The Id is bogus, I don't know what you want from me."
} catch (NameException ex) {
    warn(ex.getMessage()); // "The name doesn't match the Id, but here's the Item for that Id anyways"
} catch (ItemException ex) {
    fail("Duh! I reported to the dev, something happened");
    emailToAdmin(ex.getMessage()); // "The Item has some inconsistent data in the DB"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyException extends Exception{
       int x;
       MyException(int y) {
         x=y;
       }
       public String toString(){
         return ("Exception Number =  "+x) ;
      }
    }

    public class JavaException{
       public static void main(String args[]){
      try{
           throw new MyException(45);

      }
     catch(MyException e){
        System.out.println(e) ;
     }
    }
}

output: Exception Number = 45
```